# facebook connect stop working on live server

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have server connect implemented using official php library and it was working until last 2 weeks ago. Currently I am getting authentication fail error when trying to use the website with facebook connect.

When I run the exact the same code on my localhost and go to facebook app center and change the host to localhost code works with no problem.

I checked following:

1. if curl is still enabled
2. if permission of files are set correctly

Not sure what can be the issue?

Error is as follows:

```
OAuthException: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."
```

I don't store access tokens and facebook class is creating the session, so I am not sure why it just stop working

Comment: So have you send the user through the login flow to generate a fresh access token?

Comment: Yup flow is following 1 User come to site, I check $uid = $FACEBOOK->getUser(); $user = $FACEBOOK->api('/me');
  } catch (Exception $e){ //  here I get exception
  }, when this is empty I generate login url and when clicked it return to the same page. and on return /me was working, but now it always throws exception. This used to work